# Date/time to Time

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

I have `Datetime` field which outputs data like:

```
30/04/2016 5:05 PM
```

Now I want to convert it to only time format using formula field

Desired result

```
17:05
```

How it is possible using a formula field?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try like this.

```
 Datetime d = system.newInstance(2016, 04, 30, 05, 05, 10);//30/04/2016 5:05 PM
 String myDate = d.format('h:mm a');
 system.debug(':::::myDate:::'+myDate); // 5:05 PM
```

if you want to use in formula try this, But It is show GMT time zone

```
SUBSTITUTE(TEXT( datetime__c ), TEXT(DATEVALUE(datetime__c )), '')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought,  I am talking in formula field, not apex

Comment: Please try this
SUBSTITUTE(TEXT( datetime__c ), TEXT(DATEVALUE(datetime__c )), '')

Answer (score 3):

You can do it today with TIMEVALUE() function that has been released as part of Time field (currently in Beta).

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_field_time_type_beta.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the formula if the datetime format is fixed, which will give you GMT timezone value.

`TRIM(MID(TEXT(Test__c),12,5))`